# Eclipse RCP: Trying to add build script of plugin to existing rcp build script

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ant, eclipse-rcp, pde

I have an existing and working (ANT,PDE) build for my eclipse rcp.

Now I have another developer who is developing a plugin for this rcp product.

I have the following new requirement:

The plugin of the new developer should be part of the existing build process but I'm not allowed to simple add the new source and build from it. *(Which I did previously and worked fine!)*

I'm expected to build the plugin of the new developer with a build script that does not exist yet. I found out that the way to build a plugin without the IDE is to define an ANT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="plugin_export" name="build">
    <target name="plugin_export">
        <pde.exportPlugins destination="\export\" exportSource="false" exportType="directory" plugins="com.some.plugin" useJARFormat="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

I can build this plugin from the command line like that:

```
java.exe -jar
 "C:\Program Files\Eclipse_3.7.2_WIN32\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar"
 -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner
 -f "D:\source\com.new.plugin\build.xml"
 -data "D:\elipse_workspace"
```

So basically I'm specifying the equinox launcher, the antRunner, the build file AND an **eclipse workspace** that contains the path to the source of the plugin.

So I can build the plugin of the other developer ONLY when I have a workspace that contains the location to a project with the source. I don't understand why I can't directly build from sources? It is nearly impossible to use a workspace folder on a build server.

Since I can't get my head around how to get ride of the **-data** parameter I was thinking about adding the build script of the new plugin to my existing product build but I don't even know where to start since I know nothing about PDE.

So here is my existing (ANT,PDE) build: How can I solve my problem?

```
<!--
    Ant Build file for ****
-->
<project name="com.my.package.name.build" default="buildFull">
    <property file="build.properties" />


    <!--
        PDE Build for *****

        init step

        Create Build directories and copy all plugins and features
    -->
    <target name="init">
        <property name="resPath" location="${ant.file}/../../resources"/>       
        <mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}" />
        <mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}/plugins" />
        <mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}/features" />

        <!-- Copy all plugins into a source folder-->
        <copy todir="${buildDirectory}/plugins">
            <fileset dir="../..">
                <include name="**" />
                <exclude name="*/bin/" />
                <exclude name="*.feature/**" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>


        <!-- Features -->
        <copy todir="${buildDirectory}/features">
            <fileset dir="../..">
                <include name="*.feature/**" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!--
        Start PDE Build
    -->
    <target name="pde-build">
        <java classname="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-application" />
            <arg value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner" />
            <arg value="-buildfile" />
            <arg value="${eclipseLocation}/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_${pdeBuildPluginVersion}/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml" />
            <arg value="-Dtimestamp=${timestamp}" />
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${eclipseLocation}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_${equinoxLauncherPluginVersion}.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

    <!--
        Clean Build directory
    -->

    <target name="clean">
        <!-- <delete dir="${buildDirectory}" /> -->
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="clean, init, pde-build" />

    <!-- ================================= 
          target: buildFull              
         ================================= -->
    <target name="buildFull" depends="build" description="Builds until executable version is available">
        <available file="${buildDirectory}/${buildLabel}/${buildId}-${baseos}.${basews}.${basearch}.zip" property="buildZipOK"/>
        <antcall target="unzipBuildOutputAndCopyExe"/>
    </target>

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
          target: unzipBuildOutput                      
         - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
    <target name="unzipBuildOutputAndCopyExe" if="buildZipOK">
        <!-- unzip file  -->
         <unzip src="${buildDirectory}/${buildLabel}/${buildId}-${baseos}.${basews}.${basearch}.zip" dest="${buildDirectory}/${buildLabel}/${buildId}-${baseos}.${basews}.${basearch}"/>                    
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: use the eclipse-pde tag unless you really mean Partial-Differential Equations.